# Disable mouse button bindings in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, mouse, xmouse

I use X-Mouse to edit the bindings of the side keys on my mouse, and normally they're set to switch to either the left or right virtual desktop. However, whenever I start up Chrome, X-Mouse no longer detects my side button clicks (or in fact, any of my buttons apart from the middle wheel scrolling), and the only time they work is when I am in Chrome; even then, only the default functions of forward and back in Chrome occur.